# How to return messages from child threads to main thread(method) in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-threads

I have a HashMap of people who want to communicate with each other as follows:

```
{zidane=[rooney, rooney, rooney, scholes, rooney], rooney=[scholes, messi, scholes], scholes=[ronaldo], ronaldo=[rooney, messi, scholes], messi=[zidane]}
```

Here, each person in the key will have their own threads in which they will send a message to each person in their list and receive a response.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Master {
    public Map callsMap = new HashMap<String, List>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Master m = new Master();
        m.readFile();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List>> it = m.callsMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, List> pair = it.next();
            String caller = pair.getKey();
            List receiverList = pair.getValue();
            SubTasks st = new SubTasks(caller, receiverList);
            Thread thread = new Thread(st);
            thread.start();
            //st.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

The `master` class will iteratively create a thread for every key in the HashMap. Please note that the `readFile` method will just read from a text file and produce the input (into `callsMap` variable) I have mentioned above. It is not particularly important for this context so I have omitted it here.

I have the `SubTasks` class which extends the `Thread` class and creates messages for each interaction. This class will not create any additional threads but just operate on the caller and receiver list it received as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

public class SubTasks extends Thread {
    private String caller;
    private List receiverList;
    private volatile String returnMessage;

    SubTasks(String s, List l){
        caller = s;
        receiverList = l;
    }

    public void setMessage(String msg){
        returnMessage = msg;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return returnMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0; i < receiverList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(receiverList.get(i)+" received intro message from "+caller +" ["+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]");
            returnMessage = caller+" received reply message from "+receiverList.get(i) +" ["+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]";
            //setMessage(returnMessage);
            System.out.println(returnMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the desired output if I print the messages in the child threads for all 26 pairs.

```
zidane received message from messi [1592117172946]
rooney received message from ronaldo [1592117172946]
scholes received message from rooney [1592117172946]
rooney received message from zidane [1592117172946]
ronaldo received message from scholes [1592117172946]
messi received reply from zidane [1592117172989]
ronaldo received reply from rooney [1592117172989]
...
...
```

How do I pass these messages into the main thread (method) and print it there instead of the child threads? I tried using `getter-setter` methods but since the threads will execute randomly, there is no way to call the `getter` methods properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to you to use `Executor` framework `Callable` interface and `Futures` in your usecase, since everything you need is already solve. Rewriting the class would help you to solve it properly.

```
     public class Master {
        public Map callsMap = new HashMap<String, List>();

            public static void main(String[] args){
                Master m = new Master();
                m.readFile();
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);// or some desired number
                List<Future<String>> returnFutures = new ArrayList<>();
                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List>> it = m.callsMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<String, List> pair = it.next();
                    String caller = pair.getKey();
                    List receiverList = pair.getValue();
                    returnFutures.add(executorService.submit(new SubTasks(caller, receiverList) ));
                }
                executorService.shutdown();
                while(executorService.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
                for(Future<String> returnFuture: returnFutures){
                     /* returnFuture.get() will have the returned value from the thread, if the thread has completed execution, 
                     otherwise it will wait for the completion*/
                    System.out.println(returnFuture.get());

                }
            }
    }
```

and

```
    public  class SubTasks implements Callable<String> {
        private String caller;
        private List receiverList;
        private volatile String returnMessage;

        SubTasks(String s, List l){
            caller = s;
            receiverList = l;
        }

        public void setMessage(String msg){
            returnMessage = msg;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return returnMessage;
        }

        @Override
        public String call (){
            for (int i = 0; i < receiverList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(receiverList.get(i)+" received intro message from "+caller +" ["+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]");
                returnMessage = caller+" received reply message from "+receiverList.get(i) +" ["+System.currentTimeMillis()+"]";
                return returnMessage;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to return two statements from a single thread to the main function. How can I do that? As the call function will only be able to return a single statement.